# Xcode 7.3.1 view controller in storyboard disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I'm making an iOS app using Bluetooth. The app is supposed to show a list of Bluetooth device when the button "Bluetooth" is clicked. The list is a tableView shown as a popOver view controller.
When I turn on my computer the next day, the popOver view controller disappeared, but you can still see it in the list on the left side(Bluetooth device scene), and it is there when running it in simulator. But it is not visible or clickable in the interface builder.
I did nothing but closed my laptop, and opened it the next day. It's not that I'm using the wrong w/h size. I've tried that. Anyone know what's going on? Thanks a lot.
[Screen shot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBVYm.png)

Comment: Try right click storyboard > open as > source code, then right click storyboard > open as > interface builder.

Comment: Tried it, but it's still the same...

Comment: By the way, so far I've tried restarting laptop, and Xcode, opening as source code and as interface builder again.

Comment: from my experience, xcode is not perfect at all, it contains many bugs and ordinary people cant see those bugs so it might be less exhausting to start over again the project.... I did it many times

Comment: Actually this is my second time starting over this project...It happened before. Last time I accidentally deleted the storyboard file. I restored it from the trash bin, and put it back by adding new files to the project. After that the pop over view controller become invisible. It was shown after I created a new project, and copied all files to the new project. But now, it is invisible again...I hope I don't need to start a new project everyday....